# 3D Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) in CUDA for electromagnetics

Tags: cuda

I saw the FDTD3D sample provided in the CUDA-SDK, but there is no documentation about it. Has someone tried to modify it for computing a solution to Maxwell's equations or it's better to write everything from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a late answer provided here to remove this question from the unanswered list.

As the OP mentioned, the CUDA-SDK provides a 3D Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) solver and a description of this solver is provided in the paper

[P. Micikevicius, "3D Finite Difference Computation on GPUs using CUDA"](https://www.google.it/search?q=3D+Finite+Difference+Computation+on+GPUs+using+CUDA&oq=3D+Finite+Difference+Computation+on+GPUs+using+CUDA&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1136j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

The code has been optimized for Tesla cards and uses shared memory to load slices of the 3D computational domain to enable fast stencil evaluations (reducing *read redundancy*). The code is not for electromagnetic applications as the updating rule is the following:

[image]

but it can be easily extended to electromagnetics. A good reference in this respect implementing a 3D FDTD code for electromagnetics and taking particular care to the efficiency of the stencil calculation is the following:

[V. Demir, A.Z. Elsherbeni, "Compute Unified Device Architecture (CUDA) Based Finite-
Difference Time-Domain (FDTD) Implementation", *Appl. Comput. Electromagn. Soc. J.*, vol. 25, n. 4, pp. 303-314, Apr. 2010](http://www.engineering.olemiss.edu/~atef/pdfs/journal_papers/2010/CUDA_Based_FDTD_Implementation.pdf)

which also provides a thorough discussion on the effective stencil calculation. Electromagnetic fields are vector fields and in this case the above update equation is replaced by six equations for the three components of electric and magnetic fields. For example, the update equation for the `x`-component of the magnetic field is

[image]

Finally, it should be mentioned that another source of discussion for 3D FDTD in CUDA is the Parallel ForAll blog, see

[Finite Difference Methods in CUDA C/C++, Part 1](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/finite-difference-methods-cuda-cc-part-1/)

and

[Finite Difference Methods in CUDA C++, Part 2](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/finite-difference-methods-cuda-c-part-2/)

p.s. The formulas appearing in this answer have been generated by using [mimetex](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html).